# Is it possible to add display panel brightness support to an existing Windows display driver?

Tags: windows, driver, brightness, miniport

So, keep the stock driver, but add some other driver plus Windows register configuration that tells Windows how to do brightness at the hardware level?

Is that even possible within Windows? Or does it need to be built into the graphics driver itself?

(I'm specifically asking about Intel's "Legacy Backlight Brightness (LBB) I/O Register". Which works on a lot of Intel GPUs.)

For reference, I'm not really grokking all the jargon: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569755(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Probably not. It sounds like Windows expects the brightness control interface to be provided by the same driver instance that provides the display interface (obviously, this makes it easier for Windows to know *which* display brightness it's adjusting in multi-monitor situations). Other potential issues include (1) getting access to the necessary hardware interface (it may be claimed exclusively by the display driver) and (2) assuming you can change the value, the display driver - being unaware of you - may overwrite it.

Comment: The Intel display driver does not overwrite the brightness value. I can override the ACPI DSDT programming to write the necessary single byte to the PCI register. Then Windows 8+ can change the brightness natively. But to override the ACPI DSDT within Windows you need to disable driver signing, not something I would recommend anyone. Other option might be the mentioned screen driver, do maybe the override in GRUB and chainload Windows.